# Change display size of maths equations in typst

Tags: typst

In typst I can set the font size using

```
set text(9pt, font: "Linux Libertine", lang: "de")
```

inside of `#let project(title: "...", authors: (...), body) = {...}`

I want to make a cheat sheet for an exam using typst and I would like to display all maths equations as small and tight as possible (>=9pt).
I changed the font size but it appears that the size of displayed equations did not change. How can I do that globaly?

What I found in the documentation was [this](https://typst.app/docs/reference/math/sizes/)

```
display(
content,
cramped: boolean,
) -> content
```

but while the cramped option is helpful, I dont know how to set the display size of the equation and I dont know how to do that globally without needing to wrap every single of the many equations inside this function.

Answer (score 4):

To change the size of math relative to the rest of your content, you can use

```
#show math.equation: set text(9pt)
```

which specifically resizes math. You may also be interested in the [`inline`](https://typst.app/docs/reference/math/sizes/#inline) function which forces inline style for display equations.